# Check if method B is also called when method A is called in Archunit

Tags: java, archunit

I'm trying to write a test to ensure all `Hello` instances which calls A method must also call B method (order is not important), where `Hello` class is a part of some 3rd party library. Is it possible to test it with ArchUnit?

```java
class Hello {
  void A() {...}
  void B() {...}
  void C() {...}
}
```

```java
Hello hello1 = new Hello();
hello1.A()

Hello hello2 = new Hello();
hello2.A()
hello2.B()

// hello1: fail
// hello2: success
```

This is what I have so far. If I'm in the right way, what I need is a `callsBMethod()` described predicate.

```java
ArchRuleDefinition.methods().that().areDeclaredIn(Hello.class)
                .and().haveName("A")
                .should().onlyBeCalled().byCodeUnitsThat(<callsBMethod()>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use a custom [predicate](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/base/DescribedPredicate.html), e.g. this one (using `import static` …[`DescribedPredicate.describe`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/base/DescribedPredicate.html#describe(java.lang.String,java.util.function.Predicate))):

```java
    describe("call Hello.B()", codeUnit -> codeUnit.getCallsFromSelf().stream()
        .map(JavaAccess::getTarget)
        .anyMatch(target ->
            target.getOwner().isEquivalentTo(Hello.class)
            && target.getName().equals("B") && target.getParameterTypes().isEmpty()
        )
    )
```

The predicate is basically for [the code unit's calls](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaCodeUnit.html#getCallsFromSelf()), checking that some [call's target (the method being called)](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaAccess.html#getTarget()) is the right method (in the right class).